# How do i get and use information from a Sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my code and my CarsDbHelper, CarsContract for my CarsEntry.

It has no problems, but I am unsure from here on how to use information I have put in a Sqlite database.

```
String current_car_name = "TOYOTA YARIS";
String current_car_colour = "GREY";
int current_car_age = 3;

CarsDbHelper mDbHelper = new CarsDbHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,current_car_name);
    values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_COLOUR,current_car_colour);
    values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE,current_car_age);
    long newRowId = db.insert(CarsEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String[] projection = {
        CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
        CarsEntry.COLUMN_COLOUR,
        CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE
};

public void button (View view) {
    String selection = CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {current_car_name};

    TextView car_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    car_name.setText();

    TextView car_colour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colour);
    car_colour.setText();

    TextView car_age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);
    car_age.setText();
}
```

Comment: Probably getting Invalid Context issue. so Create `CarsDbHelper` class object inside `onCreate` method and call `db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();` in onCreate method

Comment: Why do you insert data immediately in onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

> I am still a bit confused on how to input this data into my TextViews.

You type in them... Did you mean get values out of them?

First off, the purpose of the "helper" object is to help you not expose a `SQLiteDatabase` object.

Make a `Car` class and an `addCar(Car car)` method in your helper.

```
public long addCar(Car car) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,car.getName());
    values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_COLOUR,car.getColour());
    values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE,car.getAge());

    long newRowId = db.insert(CarsEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    return newRowId;
}
```

Then, in the Activity, you need to set the helper in `onCreate`, not outside

```
CarsDbHelper mDbHelper;
TextView mCarName, mCarColour, mCarAge;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCarName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);    
    mCarColour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colour);
    mCarAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);

    mDbHelper = new CarsDbHelper(this);  // Moved in here
}

public void button (View view) {
    String name = mCarName.getText().toString();
    String colour = mCarColour.getText().toString();
    String age = mCarAge.getText().toString();

    Car c = new Car(name, colour, Integer.parseInt(age));
    mDbHelper.addCar(c); // This is the helper method
}
```

If you want to get data out of the database, you need a ListView and an Adapter (such as CursorAdapter)

If you would like to not mess with the details of raw SQLite, see the [Room Persistence library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)

Comment: Thanks but I want to get data out of the database

Comment: I don't see any attempt of that in your question, so where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I looked onto android studio resources and it said i should use a String projection but and a cursor but from then on Im not sure what to do.

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Answer (score -1):

First, you should create db instance in onCreate Function.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
TABLE_NAME,                     // The table to query
projection,                               // The columns to return
selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
null,                                     // don't group the rows
null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
sortOrder                                 // The sort order
);
```

Copied from Android Dev Site.

You will get cursor, iterate through it as follows:

```
if(!cursor.moveToFirst()) 
   //No Data 
//cache columns indexes in integers 
int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("id"); 
... 
while(cursor.moveToNext()){ 
  String id = cursor.getString(id); //Same for boolean, Int, long, etc. 
  ... 
} 
//Never forget to close cursor 
cursor.close();
```

Comment: Sorry but I am still a bit confused on how to input this data into my TextViews.